# HERE API show map based on the calculated route

Tags: rest, here-api

I want to show a map of the calculated route (truck). How can I do that?
Currently the map showed is based on the lat&long, so not on the calculated route.

[image of C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox9LG.png)

Comment: Please provide us some code on what your inputs are etc.. for us to help you better.

Comment: I've added an image with the C# code I have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display a map with a polyline(route) on it you can use one of the below two solutions:

1. **Maps API for Javascript**: A polyline is created using the H.map.Polyline class, passing in an H.geo.LineString holding the points of the line. The look-and-feel of the polyline can be altered by adding the style parameter. Read more at developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/geoshapes/polyline-on-the-map

`

```
function addPolylineToMap(map) {
 var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
 lineString.pushPoint({lat:53.3477, lng:-6.2597});
 lineString.pushPoint({lat:51.5008, lng:-0.1224});
 lineString.pushPoint({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508});
 lineString.pushPoint({lat:52.5166, lng:13.3833});
 map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
 lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4 }}
 ));
}
```

`
 2. **Map Image API**: Replace app id and app code values with actuals. Read more at developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map-image/map-image-with-routes

`GET https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/route?r0=52.5338%2C13.2966%2C52.538361%2C13.325329&r1=52.540867%2C13.262444%2C52.536691%2C13.264561%2C52.529172%2C13.268337%2C52.528337%2C13.273144%2C52.52583%2C13.27898%2C52.518728%2C13.279667&m0=52.5338%2C13.2966%2C52.538361%2C13.325329&m1=52.540867%2C13.262444%2C52.518728%2C13.279667&lc0=00ff00&sc0=000000&lw0=6&lc1=ff0000&sc1=0000ff&lw1=3&w=500&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxxx`